# Smallest possible perimeter of a triangle if area is 135

Tags: geometry

What is the smallest possible perimeter of a (flat, regular) triangle if the area is 135?

I tried various equations but I always ended up with two unknown variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You want an equilateral triangle.  That should give you a single equation.

Comment: You can see this by first fixing the base of the triangle, and this fixes the height $h$ (since the area is given). So take a line parallel to the base and find the point on it which minimises the perimeter - the area takes care of itself - you should get an isosceles triangle. This shows that if your triangle has two sides of different lengths, you can choose the third side as a base and find a triangle of smaller perimeter on the same base with the same area by equalising the sides. If there is a minimum, the sides must all be equal.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it.

Answer (score 6):

The following proof is more complicated than the calculus approach. However, it uses some interesting ideas.

Our problem is equivalent to showing that among all triangles with a given **perimeter**, the equilateral triangle has maximum area.

Let the perimeter be $p$, and let $s=p/2$ be the half-perimeter. If the sides are $a$, $b$, and $c$, then $a+b+c=2s$. By [Heron's Formula,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) the area of the triangle is
$$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}.$$

We want to maximize area, so equivalently we want to maximize $s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$. But since the perimeter is *given*, so constant, we want to maximize
$(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$ under the constraint $a+b+c=2s$.

Now we quote the case $n=3$ of the important [Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) known as AM-GM to high school students who are serious about math contests.

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be positive. Then 
$$\frac{x+y+z}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{xyz},$$
with equality only when $x=y=z$.

Let $x=s-a$, $y=s-b$, and $z=s-c$. Then $x+y+z=s$, and therefore
$$\frac{s}{3} \ge  \sqrt[3]{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)},$$
with equality precisely when $s-a=s-b=s-c$, meaning that $a=b=c$.
Thus
$$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\le \sqrt{s(s^3/27)}=\frac{s^2}{3\sqrt{3}},$$ 
with equality only for the equilateral triangle with perimeter $2s$.